# Excel 2003 vba chart failed

Tags: excel, vba, charts, excel-2003

So im getting a chart failed error and it seems like it is because of my name WBname but i cant figure it out.  Had a similar question earlier but since this is a little different i thought i would make a new question.  Here is the code im having issues with:

```
Dim WBname As String
WBname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
Worksheets(WBname).Activate
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("B4:B5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("B3")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("C4:C5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("C3")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("D4:D5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("D3")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("I4:I5000")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("I3")
```

WBname is coming out like i want but im still getting errors.

```
Method 'SeriesCollection' of object '_Chart' Failed
```

The sheet name is dynamically changing and matches WBname FYI.

EDIT: i added

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
```

and it seems to work

Comment: What is the Error ?!?!?!

Comment: i get Method 'SeriesCollection' of object '_Chart' Failed

Comment: i added ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000") and it seems to work now but i dont understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are trying to assign values to series which is not there ;)

You need to add the series first and then assign values to it. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim WBname As String
    WBname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
    Worksheets(WBname).Activate

    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries '<~~~~~ SEE THIS

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("B4:B5000")
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("B3")
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

You are getting extra series `sometimes` because your cursor is in the data for example in Cell `B5` or `I10` or some other cell. Excel by default adds the series when you say `Charts.Add` in such a scenario. Ensure that the none of your data is selected when you run the macro. An alternative is to delete the series collection after `Charts.Add`. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim WBname As String
    Dim i As Long

    WBname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
    Worksheets(WBname).Activate
    Charts.Add

    With ActiveChart
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = .SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
            .SeriesCollection(i).Delete
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0

        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("B4:B5000")
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("B3")

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("C4:C5000")
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("C3")

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
        .SeriesCollection(3).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("D4:D5000")
        .SeriesCollection(3).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("D3")

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(4).XValues = Worksheets(WBname).Range("A4:A5000")
        .SeriesCollection(4).Values = Worksheets(WBname).Range("I4:I5000")
        .SeriesCollection(4).Name = Worksheets(WBname).Range("I3")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When i used that i would an extra data series with no data in it

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand what you just said.

Comment: when i added ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries to my code i had a 5th series (should only have 4).  But when i took it out i have only 4 series like i should.  I might be doing something else wrong though

Comment: The code which is posted in your question doesn't show that you have any series (You say there are 4?) You are using `Charts.Add` and then directly assigning values to a non-existant seriescollection...

Comment: i updated the code above to reflect the remaining portion of code

Comment: You are missing one `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` after `ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers`

Comment: Yea thats what i was trying to say, when i add it there, i get an extra series being ploted in which it has no data but still shows up.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. That is because your cursor in the data when you create the chart. Excel by default adds the series when you say `Charts.Add` Ensure that the none of your data is selected when you run the macro. An alternative is to delete the series collection after `Charts.Add` :)

Comment: I have updated the post above. You will have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling what Sheet you want to work on.
(assuming that Workbook is really needed, that is not the case most of the time) :

```
Workbooks(WBname).Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:A5000")
```

should work better.

(in these case, just use the macro recorder to get the proper way of doing it and adapt it to your needs after)

Comment: I cant use sheet1 because the sheet name dynamically changes and the sheet name matches WBname

Comment: Well... use Workbooks(WBname).Sheets(1) or Workbooks(WBname).Sheets(WBName)